# Why sometimes payable date is BEFORE the ex-dividend date?

Tags: options, ex-dividend-date

Rarely, but quite consistently I come across the situation when the payable date precedes the ex-dividend date. 
A couple of examples:
http://www.cboe.com/publish/TTStockSM/05-421.pdf
http://www.cboe.com/publish/TTStockSM/05-422.pdf

What does it mean? How's that possible? Notice that in these situations the stock reacts on the Payable date, not on ex-dividend date, as normally would be the case

Comment: Relevant: [When am I entitled to participate in a stock split? — record date, split date, ex date](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/129819/when-am-i-entitled-to-participate-in-a-stock-split-record-date-split-date-e)

Answer (score 3):

Do you realise that the examples you have given are for stock splits not for dividends, that is why the date payable is before the ex-date for the split.

The payments for the split occur on 30th June and the first day the stock trades with the new split is on the next trading day, being the ex-date, 1st July.

Comment: So, the splits always have a payable date set as the last day still trading under the original multiplier? I indeed did not notice the fact that these two were splits - I was just checking the cases (and there are a lot of them) when the price correction happens either before of after the ex-date. In the examples I showed previously it corrected 1 day before, here, for example, it corrected 1 day after: http://www.cboe.com/publish/TTStockSM/16-219.pdf